# MVVM - Validating the model when a field in the viewmodel is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, ef-database-first

I'm using the MVVMLight libraries with a Database-First EF model. I can't quite figure out how to validate the model when a certain field in my viewmodel has changed. This works fine when I'm updating individual Properties of the model as I have a call to `Validate` in the set methods. I'm not sure how this works elsewhere.

For the sake of example, I have a `Person` class (model) in my application has a property called `Name` implemented like so in the view model:

```
private Person _currentPerson; 

// Code omitted...

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is a required field.")]
public string Name
{
    get { return _currentPerson.Name; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _currentPerson.Name)
        {
            _currentPerson.Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            Validate(_currentPerson.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to create a new person, I have a method attached to a `RelayCommand` called `NewPerson` with this code:

```
public RelayCommand NewCommand { get { return _newCommand ?? (_newCommand = new RelayCommand(NewPerson)); } }

// Code omitted...

private void NewPerson()
{
    _currentPerson = new Person();
    RaisePropertyChanged(String.Empty); // Updates model and UI.
}
```

How do I now validate `_currentPerson` without calling `Validate` on every single property? Because this model class has quite a few properties... (30+).

The only thing I've tried is using reflection to iterate through all the properties of the `Person` object, but this kept causing exceptions which I didn't really understand.

**Update:**
Managed to get something working, but there has to be a better way of doing this:

```
private void NewPerson()
{
    _currentPerson = new Person();
    RaisePropertyChanged(String.Empty); // Updates model and UI.
    ValidatePerson(_currentPerson);
}

private void ValidatePerson(Person p)
{
    Validate(p.Forename, "Forename");
    Validate(p.Surname, "Surname");
    Validate(p.DateOfBirth, "DateOfBirth");
    // There's about another 30 calls to Validate here...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about validating the whole person object in your Validate() methode, not just a single property?

Comment: This doesn't work, I get the following exception: `Additional information: The type 'PersonViewModel' does not contain a public property named 'ValidatePerson'.`

Comment: Fixed it, needed to use an overloaded method to prevent that exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want separate validation logic by property, just add a separate validate all method for when the whole model needs checking. That can call your individual methods or perform something more bespoke.

Comment: Do I put this method in the viewmodel or in the model, adding the validate method to my viewmodel throws a `ArgumentException` with the message `The type 'PersonViewModel' does not contain a public property named 'ValidatePerson'.`

Comment: For what it is worth, considering you've marked an accepted answer, either would work. Put it in the model if you want that logic available elsewhere. Put it in the viewmodel, if the validation is specific to the model use in that context.